# Dealing with different date formats python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I'm using the `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")` method to try and convert the column to a datetime  column.

Now, the dates are of the form day/month/year, but in varying different formats, for example:

```
5/8/2005
13/08/05
4/2/2006
```

I get an error: `time data '13/08/05' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)` when I try and use `pd.to_datetime()`, and when I remove the formatting, pandas incorrectly transforms the dates.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dayfirst` keyword in [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
0   2005-08-05
1   2005-08-13
2   2006-02-04
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar problem once, where there were certain cases with a combination of **"Month First"** and **"Day First"**. I tackled the problem using the following code.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["5/8/2005","13/08/05","4/2/2006"]})
df.loc[:,"IsMonth"]=df.loc[:,"A"].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("/")[0])>12)
df_1=df[df.loc[:,"IsMonth"]==True]
df_2=df[~df.index.isin(df_1.index)]

df_1["A"]=pd.to_datetime(df_1["A"])
df_2["A"]=pd.to_datetime(df_2["A"])

df=pd.concat([df_1,df_2])
df.drop("IsMonth", inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Please note that the default behavior of `pd.to_datetime()` is to use `dayfirst=False`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You cannot directly handle that.  You can see [details on `datetime` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and notice that there is a `%y` and `%Y` directive, meaning 2-digit and 4-digit year, respectively.</strike> (I did not know about `dayfirst`, but I think the `apply` use case is still helpful for others.)

I would suggest creating a small function and then using that function on a column apply.  Something like this:

```py
>>> def convertYear(val):
...     (day, month, year) = val.split('/')
...     if len(year) == 2:
...         if int(year) > 40:
...             year = '19' + year
...         else:
...             year = '20' + year
...         newvals = [day, month, year]
...         return '/'.join(newvals)
...     return val
```

Then you can [call this function on the column of interest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html); something like:

```py
df.Date.apply(convertYear, axis='index') # don't use axis=0, not readability-friendly
```

Now you can finally finish with:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y"
```

---

### Here Be Dragons

Be warned: even though my function tries to be clever, **it is assuming that you have European dates** (DD/MM/YYYY), I assume this because of `13/08/05`.  In the US, it is (MM/DD/YYYY).

Because of this annoyance, proper [datetimes should be internationalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates), which is really just the East Asian style. (Maybe all of Asia??)